# Can I drag and drop tiles(gridster tiles) using keyboard

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, gridster

currently im working on gridster using which I can drag and drop tiles using the mouse.

There are **callbacks** like "**options.drag**"(call back executed when mouse is moved during dragging), "**options.start**"(call back when the drag starts) defined in **jquery.gridster.js** , are there any call backs defined when i use my **keyboard** for dragging, in other words can I make the **drag possible** using the **keyboard**.

Thanks,
Balaji